# using std::list to store vertices and the draw them with SFML

Tags: c++, sfml, vertex, vertices, stdlist

Using sfml, for some reasons I would like to store my vertices in a list like that:

```
std::list<sf::Vertex> shape{};
shape.push_back(sf::Vertex(...);
```

but I don't really know how to make the call to

```
window.draw(...);
```

I guess it should resemble something like that:

```
window.draw(shape.begin(), shape.size(), sf::LineStrip);
```

Now I guess the reason it doesn't work is because lists do not support random acces... Any idea anyone?

Comment: Why aren't you using a `std::vector` instead?

Comment: Because I'm going to be adding a lot of vertex throughout time so looking at efficiency, lists seem to be better? I actually found the solution I had to do something like draw(&(*shape.begin()), ...,...)

Comment: *"I actually found the solution I had to do something like draw(&(*shape.begin()), ...,...)"* - now you have undefined behavior, if `shape` is not a vector.

Comment: *"lists seem to be better"* - you should actually benchmark these things instead of just assuming. I haven't used linked lists in years because dynamic arrays (such as `std::vector`) perform better in most cases (and the cost of adding can be easily optimized with a `reserve`)

Comment: I'll take all your advices in account. I have many things left to learn, I'm sometimes pretty stuborn. I thank you both for taking the time to explain all this.

Answer (score 2):

SFML expects the vertices to be given in contiguous storage.  You can do this:

```
std::vector<sf::Vertex> vec(shape.begin(), shape.end()); // copy
window.draw(vec.data, vec.size(), sf::LineStrip);
```

Of course it would be more efficient to just use `vector` (or `VertexBuffer`) in the first place.

Comment: Interesting, but as you say, using vector directly is probably more efficient. Thanks!